# What does the underlined statement mean?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

-[image]

Since $T_i'$ s are trees it doesn't contain multiple edges. Why it not having the edge from G? What does the statement mean?How do I justify this claim?

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume that your source defines 'graph' in a way that allows two nodes to be directly connected by more than one edge, otherwise the construct '$G'$' wouldn't be a graph *[note: other sources would call this a 'multigraph']*.  Let us proceed as if this is the case:

As $T_1'$, $T_2'$, and $T_3'$ are spanning trees of $G'$, they consist of edges from $G'$, with each pair of nodes connected by at most one edge.  Each of these edges may be either an original edge of $G$ or a parallel edge.  Let us suppose $T_1'$ (say) contains an original edge of $G$.  By disjointness, neither $T_2'$ nor $T_3'$ contains this edge.  BUT: It is possible that $T_2'$ (say) contains the matching parallel edge.  But that means $T_3'$ can contain *neither* the original edge *nor* the parallel edge.  Now when we convert back to subgraphs of $G$, we find that $T_1$ and $T_2$ both contain the original edge (in $T_2$'s case because the parallel edge was replaced with the original), but $T_3$ doesn't, so the triple-intersection *between that edge's nodes* is empty (of edges).  This analysis generalizes to all other possible combinations.  That is what the underlined sentence means: Since at most two of $T_1'$, $T_2'$, $T_3'$ can contain both an original edge and its parallel, at most two of $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$ can contain that original edge.